# Python, is this a bug, append to a list within a tuple results in None?

Tags: python, list, append, tuples, iterable-unpacking

This is one of the shortest examples I've written in a long time

I create and update a tuple3

```
In [65]: arf=(0,1,[1,2,3])

In [66]: arf=(arf[0],arf[1], arf[2] )

In [67]: arf
Out[67]: (0, 1, [1, 2, 3])
```

So the reassignment worked.

Now I try to change it's contents.

```
In [69]: arf=(arf[0],arf[1], [2] )

In [70]: arf
Out[70]: (0, 1, [2])

In [71]: arf=(arf[0],arf[1], arf[2].append(3) )

In [72]: arf
Out[72]: (0, 1, None)
```

I get back None??? Hey, what gives? Sorry I'm a python noob.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`list.append()` always returns `None`

so `arf[2].append(3)` will append `3` to `arf` and return `None`

you never get to see this change to `arf[2]` because you are immediately rebinding `arf` to the newly created tuple

Perhaps this is what you want

```
arf = (arf[0], arf[1], arf[2]+[3])
```

Comment: argh, I'm trying to squeeze it all into a lambda function. Is there a way to avoid creating an intermediate variable?

Comment: @BryanHunt stop trying to squeeze it into a lambda: just use a named function, you lose nothing.

Comment: Comparing it with Scala code, this wikipedia page made me do it http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)#Folds_in_various_languages I want to create a frequency plot with matplotlib

Answer (score 3):

The `list.append` method changes the list in place and returns `None`. This isn't a bug, this is just how the `append` method works.

Comment: The idea behind this behavior is called Command-Query-Separation (e.g. http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CommandQuerySeparation.html)

Answer (score 1):

`append` doesn'[t return the new list, it modifies the old one in-place:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = a.append(4)
>>> print b
None
>>> print a
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on gnibbler's answer, list.append() changes the list itself, but it doesn't return the new value of the list. It returns `None`. So your command 71 changes the value of arf[2] in the way you wanted, but then it immediately returns `None` and sets arf[2] to that.

The self-reference in your example obfuscates things a bit, but if you try a command like `someothervariable=arf[2].append(3)`, you'll see how it works. `someothervariable` is set to `None` and arf[2] has 3 appended without an explicit assignment statement.