# python dictionary return None

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this

```
dict_a = {}
dict_a["key1"] = [["1","2"]]
```

i want to concatenate the value `[["1","2"]]` inside this dictionary with a string `3`. So I did something like this:

```
new_list = list(dict_a["key1"])
dict_a["key1"] = new_list.append("3")
```

when i print the dictionary with the key `key1` it gives me a `None` instead of [["1","2"], "3"]

```
print dict_a["key1"]
```

Cane someone explain why I got a "None"?

Comment: append() doesn't return a list, it updates the one you're appending to.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python, is this a bug, append to a list within a tuple results in None?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617906/python-is-this-a-bug-append-to-a-list-within-a-tuple-results-in-none)

Comment: And of [why does python's list.append evaluate to false?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1682567)

Comment: And of [Appending item to lists - python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2505529), etc.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I can.

There are essentially 2 kinds of methods:

1. Those which create and return a new object.
2. Those which modify the object operated on in-place. Instead of returning `self` (which would in some situations quite handy), they return `None` by convention.

`list.append()` is one of the latter and thus returns `None`.

So you should replace

```
dict_a["key1"] = new_list.append("3")
```

with

```
new_list.append("3")
dict_a["key1"] = new_list
```

.

Comment: or `dict_a["key1"] += ["3"]`

Answer (score 1):

The append() method doesn't return any value, so by default it returns `None`. If you assign its result to a variable, it will be `None`. That's why you get `None` if you print that value.